# Assignment of data-member in read-only structure, class in STL set

Tags: c++, stl

The minimal example of the problem I'm having is reproduced below:

```
#include <set>
using namespace std;

class foo {
public:
  int value, x;
  foo(const int & in_v) {
   value = in_v;
   x = 0;
  }
  bool operator<(const foo & rhs) const {
   return value < rhs.value; 
 }
};

int main() {
  foo y(3);
  set<foo> F;
  F.insert(y);

  // Now try to modify a member of the set
  F.begin()->x=1;
  return 0;
}
```

With the error `error: assignment of data-member ‘foo::value’ in read-only structure`. I feel like I'm missing something simple here, but why am I unable to modify the member `x` in my class?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Objects in a `set` are immutable; if you want to modify an object, you need to:

1. make a copy of the object from the `set`,
2. modify the copy,
3. remove the original object from the `set`, and
4. insert the copy into the `set`

It will look something like this:

```
std::set<int> s;
s.insert(1);

int x = *s.begin(); // (1)
x+= 1;              // (2)
s.erase(s.begin()); // (3)
s.insert(x);        // (4)
```

Comment: Well the immutable part makes sense now. Is this then is the standard way of editing an item in the set, with the two copies?

Comment: @Hooked:  Yes; you need to make two copies:  one to copy the old object out of the set and one to copy the new object into the set.

Answer (score 9):

Given that the "x" variable is not involved in the less-than comparison, it would be safe in this case to make "x" mutable, allowing you to modify it from within the set.  Your class definition would then become:

```
class foo {
public:
  int value;
  mutable int x;

  foo(const int & in_v) : value(in_v), x(0) { }
  bool operator<(const foo & rhs) const {
    return value < rhs.value; 
  }
};
```

And you can now use it in the std::set and modify x as you like.  In this case it is pointless to keep two copies of the data structure as the previous poster has suggested.

Comment: I like this answer MUCH better.  Thanks for adding it.

Answer (score 1):

From the definition of the `operator<` (i.e.  considering only the value `return value < rhs.value` and ignoring the `x`), I am wondering whether you want a `map` instead of a `set`. In `map`, the `second` value *is* mutable.