# GCC Tree STL data containers

Tags: c++, gcc, stl, set, multiset

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [remove_if equivalent for std::map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/800955/remove-if-equivalent-for-stdmap)

Yesterday i wrote a program, which use multiset for storing elements like this:

```
std::multiset < boost::shared_ptr < CEntity > > m_Entities;
```

Then i try to use standard algorithm `remove_if` like this:

```
std::remove_if(m_Entities.begin, m_Entities.end(), MarkedForDestroy);
```

BUT compilation failed, because if we see in GCC 4.4 implementaion of set and multiset we see that:

```
typedef typename _Rep_type::const_iterator            iterator;
typedef typename _Rep_type::const_iterator            const_iterator;
```

I was shocked. I google this moment and better that i found that this does not contradict the standard. The same for set.

How this cannot contradict if standart algorithms doesnt work? How i can better change container?

Comment: Duplicate of [remove_if equivalent for std::map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/800955/remove-if-equivalent-for-stdmap)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not use `std::remove_if` algorithm on an associative container. You need to a write a `for` loop and use the `erase` method to remove the elements. See this similar question [remove_if equivalent for std::map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/800955/remove-if-equivalent-for-stdmap) for more details.

Comment: Thanks, this is better than previous answer.

Answer (score 1):

All standard ordered/associative containers (map, set, multimap, multiset) have immutable keys (just the keys not the entire container).

As to why just look at what would need to happen every time you would change the value of the key: the key type would need somehow to notify it's container that it got changed (which would introduce a very tight and unnecessary coupling between the container & it's key type - not to mention being impossible to do for fundamental types) because the container would need to be resorted so to keep it's ordering property (which is a pretty big overhead).

Answer (score -3):

Because multiset (and also set) are **immutable** containers, i.e. elements in the container cannot be <strike>changed</strike> modified *in-place*, they can be removed, modified, and (re-)inserted.

See, for example:

- a different [set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3775414/assignment-of-data-member-in-read-only-structure-class-in-stl-set/3775485#3775485) related answer
- section 27.3.2.1 in this [tutorial](http://www.tenouk.com/Module27.html)

> In simple associative containers,
>   where the elements are the keys, the
>   elements are completely immutable; the
>   nested types iterator and
>   const_iterator are therefore the same.

Comment: I have understood this. Why this is so? Set have an order, why such problems?

Comment: No, they're [not](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/multiset/insert/).

Comment: @den bardadym: Note that `remove_if` doesn't actually "remove" the elements from the container instead it just moves the elements to the end of the container. For sequential containers moving to the end makes sense but for associative containers in which elements are stored in a sorted order, this doesn't make sense as it will break their ordering.

Comment: @Matthew Flaschen: I know that elements can be *inserted* in a set, I did not restricted that when I said "elements cannot be modified". What I meant was elements cannot be modified in place. Thats because in [multi]set the elements themselves are keys of the underlying BST, and if the keys are modified, the BST may no longer remain a BST.

Comment: @naveen: Thanks, i dont know this.

Comment: @Arun, there's a difference between the container being immutable (no modifications of any kind possible) and not allowing element replacements in-place.

Comment: @Mathew Flaschen: You are right, on literal interpretation, there is  difference. But, have you seen any immutable container per your definition? Because, AFAIK, all containers allow insert and erase (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/). It would not be a "container" if it wouldn't, isn't it?

Comment: @Arun, there are no immutable-only container classes in the C++ standard library, since it relies on `const` instead.  However, other languages certainly have them.