# Accessing member via set's NON-const iterator that doesn't affect invariants

Tags: c++, invariants, const-iterator, stdset

Let's say I have code like so:

```
#include <set>
#include <math.h>

typedef int OtherTypes;

struct MyType
{
    double Field1;
    OtherTypes MoreFields;

    MyType(double blah) :
        Field1(blah)
    {
    }

    bool operator < (const MyType &That) const
    {
        // Does not use any other member besides Field1
        return ( fabs(Field1 - That.Field1) > 1e-6 &&
                 Field1 < That.Field1 );
    }

};

int main()
{
    std::set<MyType> foo;
    std::pair< std::set<MyType>::iterator,
               bool > inchk = foo.insert(MyType(1.0));

    OtherTypes SomeVal = 1;
    if ( inchk.second )
        inchk.first->MoreFields = SomeVal; // error

}
```

How do I reassure the compiler that writing MoreFields will not affect
any invariants or will not do anything to invalidate the order of
elements in the set?

If the only recourse is to use another container such as vector, how
do I insert a new value in the sorted position while checking if one
exists already?

Comment: If it's available to you, I'm pretty sure [Boost.MultiIndex](http://www.boost.org/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html) solves your problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Assignment of data-member in read-only structure, class in STL set](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3775414/assignment-of-data-member-in-read-only-structure-class-in-stl-set)

Comment: @GManNickG -- unfortunately, my employer will not use it.  Thank you much, all the same.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but your `operator<` means you can have `a`, `b`, `c` such that `!(a < b) && !(b < a) && !(b < c) && !(c < b)`, yet still `a < c`.

Comment: Appreciate the link to the other post, @interjay -- I did search before posting, and I didn't find the one that you cross-referenced.  That said, my question isn't so much as to "Why" (which I understand), it is more a "How".  Furthermore, the accepted answer there and here (both by James McNeillis!) are significantly different.

Comment: @hvd -- Yes, I know it is not the strictest of weak orderings.

Comment: Yes, if you ask me the same question multiple times, I am likely to give different answers.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis -- I am grateful for your answer -- I accepted your response as the answer.  My point was this is a *different* question from the other one.  Finally, I am _not_ the one who asked the previous question (i.e., I surely didn't ask the question multiple times!).

Comment: Yes, when I said "you" I meant "the internet."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Declare `MoreFields` as `mutable`, or
- `const_cast` the `inchk.first` expression to remove constness, or
- encapsulate `MoreFields` within a const-qualified accessor that returns a non-const reference.

Answer (score 0):

I would think you want to use a map instead of a set.